# Facebook login API: Not redirecting to specified redirect uri after granting all permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Facebook login API works perfectly fine when the account used to login is a personal account. But there is this case where a client use a page account/business page account which is not associated to any personal account. That is when the problem occur. After granting all the permissions shown in facebook login dialog, it is supposed to close the dialog and redirects to the specified redirect uri, but it only continues to the page's profile.

Comment: Did you check the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem about the redirect uri as it is successfully redirected when the account used to login is a personal account. It seems to happen only when the account is a page/business page account